# Extracting a value error using python beautifulsoup web scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some info using beautiful soup in python using python webscraping. Here is the section.

```
<div class="result-value" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1">
<span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0">1.1</span>
<span class="result-value-unit" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.1">MB</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the 1.1 value there

Part of the Code i am using is

```
try:
    Area =soup.select(".result-value span")
    
    print Area
    
except StandardError as e:
    converted_date="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print converted_date
```

Result im getting is

```
[]
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Im new here in stackoverflow. sorry if i am not following the standards. i m reading the standard procedures i have to follow on this platform. hope i m not bothering anyone

Comment: If `soup.select` does not find anything as you specified, it will just return an empty list `[]`. So `try... except` may not capture any error in this case.

Comment: Do u have an idea why its not capturing the value there? i m following the bs4 manual

Comment: To get "to get the 1.1 value", how about trying `soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text`.

Comment: Thanks @mikeqfu But it gives error Error was 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I've tried on my own computer. `soup.find` should work okay on the posted section code in your question. I'm not sure why it gives you 'NoneType' error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyi99zhq8bxq1aw/1.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5dwmu904pre8et/2.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uod1ussoowtdt5s/3.png?dl=0

Comment: Please see my new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the value of `data-reactid`, you can get the correct element like this:

```
soup.findAll("span", {"data-reactid": ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"})
```

Comment: still [ ] is the output

Comment: and yes i know the value of data-reactid

Comment: Can you check if you actually have the source code loaded? 

print(soup.prettify())

Comment: htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
 soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

 print soup

I used this and it loads the whole code

Comment: do u have an idea why i cannot get the values?

Comment: dropbox.com/s/hyi99zhq8bxq1aw/1.png?dl=0 dropbox.com/s/k5dwmu904pre8et/2.png?dl=0 dropbox.com/s/uod1ussoowtdt5s/3.png?dl=0

Comment: Is that because there is delay in loading of the elements in question? Because `soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Again, if `soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': '.0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0'}).text` works, the code does not return any error message. You got a resultant message which at least shows your `try...except...` function is working. I guess the problem is on your `htmlfile`, which must be `bytes` rather than `str`. I'd suggest you to revise your code a little bit as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

htmlfile = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8') # if errors occur here, try: htmlfile = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'lxml')
```

And then continue with the rest.